How to change library lookup paths on Debian: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so'
I have 2 server A, B.
Server A works properly, server B doesn't.
On Server B, when I perform the command
php7.4 -d display_startup_errors=on -d display_errors=on
I get the following error:
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/gd.so (libdav1d.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

On server A, everything is fine, when I perform the command above.
On server A, when I perform lsof /usr/lib/php/20190902/gd.so
I get the following output:
COMMAND      PID     USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
php-fpm7. 453528     root mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so
php-fpm7. 453529 www-data mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so
php-fpm7. 453530 www-data mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so
php-fpm7. 453531 www-data mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so
php-fpm7. 453532 www-data mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so
php-fpm7. 453533 www-data mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so
php-fpm7. 453534 www-data mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so
php-fpm7. 453535 www-data mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so
php-fpm7. 453536 www-data mem    REG    8,1   112744 1578754 ./php/20190902/gd.so

On server B, I dont get any output, when i perform the command above.
None of the 2 server actually have a file called libdav1d.so.4 but they both have a file called libdav1d.so.6
On server A, when I perform the command
ldd /usr/lib/php/20190902/gd.so | grep libdav

I get the output
libdav1d.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdav1d.so.6 (0x00007fb671fbb000)

On Server B, when I perform the command above, I get the following output:
libdav1d.so.4 => not found
libdav1d.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdav1d.so.6 (0x00007fdc1402f000)

On server B the command
ldconfig -p | grep libdav

doesn't show libdav1d.so.4
My question is:

From where does server B get the information to look for libdav1d.so.4? Can I change the entry somewhere?


dav1d is a video decoder, why does gd need it? Is this an official gd.so?

yes, it's an official gd.so
